# Divisibility of Differents in Tower of Fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

In [Lemmermeyer's class field theory notes](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/cft.html), on page 114 there is the following claim. Let $F = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$, then let $K = F(\sqrt{-1})$. Let $F_1 = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1})$ and $F_2 = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ be the other two quadratic subfields of $K/\mathbb Q$. Then we have that
$$
\operatorname{diff}(K/F) \mid \operatorname{diff}(F_1/\mathbb Q)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\operatorname{diff}(K/F) \mid \operatorname{diff}(F_2/\mathbb Q).
$$

Why is this true? Certainly I see $\operatorname{diff}(K/F)$ divides $\operatorname{diff}(K/\mathbb Q) = \operatorname{diff}(K/F_i)\operatorname{diff}(F_i/\mathbb Q)$ for $i=1,2$ but I don't see how to get the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $K/F = F(\sqrt{-1})$ is a "relativization" of $F_1/\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$, so in particular, (i) any element generating the latter also generates the former; (ii) the trace form on the latter extends to the trace on the former. (For $F_2/\mathbb{Q}$ it's the same.)

Now to show the different of the former divides the different of the latter, we can either use (i) together with the "$(f'(\alpha))$ definition" of different, or (ii) together with the "inverse of inverse different" definition (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal#Definition), especially the Neukirch reference given (p. 198, Chapter III, Theorem 2.5) for the equivalence of definitions).

(For the special case that "relativization" preserves unramified-ness, see Neukirch p. 153, Ch. II, Sec. 7,
Proposition 7.2.)